# Best way to update android Gallery View only when backend hosting server add's image

Tags: android

I get the set of image Url's from back end service calls ,after parsing them, i download the images and display in a gallery view .I have written an Asynctask to get the response from the server in onCreate method ,my requirement is that whenever my server team add's an image in the service call, i need to update my gallery view ,otherwise i am not interested in doing an unnecessary network resource operation.How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Simple way to achieve this scenario is push notification. whenever your server team make some changes you will get the notification message. it will be better if you can get some **JSON string** in the message, so that you can parse that message into JSONObject and then perform your network operation.